# Python dict with values as tuples to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I have the following dict:

```
td = {'q1':(111,222), 'q2':(333,444)}
```

I would like to convert it to a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Query    Value1     Value2
q1       111       222
q2       333       444
```

I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(td.items())
```

The result looks like this:

```
    0         1
0   q1  (111,222)
1   q2  (333,444)
```

If it wasn't entirely obvious, I am new to python and pandas. How can I get a dictionary with values as tuples to behave as separate columns in a dataframe?

My end goal is to display percent difference between value1 and value2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Setup**

```
td = {'q1':(111,222), 'q2':(333,444)}
```

**Option 1**

```
pd.DataFrame(td).T.rename_axis('Query').add_prefix('Value').reset_index()

  Query  Value0  Value1
0    q1     111     222
1    q2     333     444
```

---

**Option 2**

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge

pd.DataFrame(
    [merge(
        {'Query': k},
        {'Value{}'.format(i): x for i, x in enumerate(v, 1)}
     ) for k, v in td.items()]
)

  Query  Value1  Value2
0    q1     111     222
1    q2     333     444
```

---

**Response to Comment**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(td).T.rename_axis('Query').add_prefix('Value')
df.assign(PctChg=df.pct_change(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]).reset_index()

  Query  Value0  Value1    PctChg
0    q1     111     222  1.000000
1    q2     333     444  0.333333
```

Or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(td).T.rename_axis('Query').add_prefix('Value')
df.eval('PctChg = Value1 / Value0 - 1', inplace=False).reset_index()

  Query  Value0  Value1    PctChg
0    q1     111     222  1.000000
1    q2     333     444  0.333333
```

Comment: I like your first option ;)

Comment: I tried option 1. I got the error "unexpected character after line continuation character".

Comment: I replaced the dictionary with the name you provided `td` so you shouldn't have a line continuation anymore.

Comment: Thank you!  Just a minute while I figure out how to mark your response as the answer...

Comment: The final step for me is to add a fourth column which is the percent change between Value1 and Value2. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: I did this, but I am just getting Nans in that column? I checked the datatypes and they are int64 for value0 and value1

Comment: I added a more direct way.

Answer (score 14):

Try this ?

```
td = {'q1':(111,222), 'q2':(333,444)}
df = pd.DataFrame(td).T
df
Out[25]: 
      0    1
q1  111  222
q2  333  444
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(td).T.rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1).add_prefix('Value')`

Answer (score 7):

Using `from_dict`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'q1':(111,222), 'q2':(333,444)}, orient='index')
```

Returns:

```
      0    1
q1  111  222
q2  333  444
```

---

Throw in some formatting:

```
df.columns = 'Value' + df.columns.to_series().add(1).astype(str)
df.index.name = 'Query'
```

You get:

```
       Value1  Value2
Query                
q1        111     222
q2        333     444
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define the `data` and `index` using the dictionary iterators:

```
import pandas as pd
td = {'q1':(111,222), 'q2':(333,444)}
pd.DataFrame(data=list(td.values()), index=list(td.keys()))
```

should produce a DataFrame:

```
        0       1
    q1  111     222
    q2  333     444
```